# Problemas com requisição de XML com AJAX

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

Estou com um problema fiz um código Javascript para exibir via AJAX um XML com uma lista:
Meu XML está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<telas>
<item>
<title>Lorem ipsum</title>
<title>Dolor sit amet</title>
</item>

<item>
<title>Lorem ipsum dolor</title>
<title>Ipsum dolor sit amet</title>
<title>Ipsum dolor sit amet</title>
</item>
</telas>
```

Eu quero listar o conteudo da tag `<item>` (do XML) e colocar dentro do `<li>` (no meu HTML) a tag `<title>` (do XML), mas só mostra o conteúdo da primeira tag `title`, eu preciso que mostre todas as tags `<title>` que eu tiver no XML.

Creio que o problema seja essa parte do meu código:

```
exibir+=tela[valor].getElementsByTagName('title')[0|1].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Como eu posso alterar isso para que funcione de forma adequada (a que eu quero)?

Comment: Pode postar um pouco mais do seu código js para dar contexto? Uma coisa: `[0|1]` nessa sua linha vai sempre valer como `[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem, o que deseja é criar um lista baseada nos items do XML?
Se for isso, é possível fazer da seguinte forma:

```
//levando em conta que o XML já esta "parseado" dentro da variável 'xml'
// e sua lista em uma chamada 'ul'

//pega todos os items...
var items = xml.getElementsByTagName("item");

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){ //itera sobre os mesmos
   var item = items[i];
   var li = document.createElement("li"); //cria um LI para cada Item
   ul.appendChild(li); //insere na UL

   var titles = item.getElementsByTagName("title"); //recupera os titles

   for(var j = 0; j < titles.length; j++){
       var title = titles[j]; 
       var span = document.createElement("span"); //aqui criei um span para cada
       li.appendChild(span);  //inseri no LI 
       span.textContent = title.textContent; //e passei o valor do title para o span

   }
}
```

o resultado desse algoritmo para o seu XML é

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      <span>Dolor sit amet</span>
   </li>
   <li>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
      <span>Ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <span>Ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = obj.getElementsByTagName('title');
y = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for(i=0;i<title.length){
    li[i].innerHTML = obj[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site. Esse código talvez resolva o problema, mas você poderia elaborar um pouco mais a resposta, com explicação da causa e da solução? Fica um conteúdo melhor para os futuros visitantes, e deve te render alguns pontos (e privilégios) no site. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Segue um script que fiz para captura de CEP:

```
$.getScript("http://www.buscarcep.com.br/?cep="+$("#cep").val()+"&formato=xml&chave=1iyeEHOY7.SVCKZSalTVl5SnTc34470", function(){
    if(resultadoCEP["resultado"] != 0){
        $('#loading').css({display:'none'});
        $('#selectEstado').fadeOut(400);
        $('#inputEstado').fadeIn(600);
        $("#rua").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["tipo_logradouro"])+' '+unescape(resultadoCEP["logradouro"])).prop("readonly", "readonly");
        $("#bairro").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["bairro"])).prop("readonly", "readonly");
        $("#cidade").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["cidade"])).prop("readonly", "readonly");
        $("#estado").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["uf"])).prop("readonly", "readonly");
        $('#numero').focus();
    }else{
        $('#inputEstado').fadeOut(400);
        $('#selectEstado').fadeIn(600);
        $("#rua").removeAttr('readonly').val('').focus();  
        $("#bairro").removeAttr('readonly').val('');  
        $("#cidade").removeAttr('readonly').val('');  
        $("#estado").removeAttr('readonly').val('');
        $('#loading').html('Endereço não encontrado.');
    }  
});
```

é necessário ter o jquery incluso na pagina. Acredito que já dê pra ter uma noção.